# How can I type annotate a decorator that takes optional arguments?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Let's say I define a decorator like this:

```py
def my_decorator(func=None, *, param=42):
    if func is None:
        return functools.partial(my_decorator, param=param)
    ...
```

This decorator can be used like this

```py
@my_decorator
def my_func(...):
    ...
```

or like this

```py
@my_decorator(param=123)
def my_func(...):
    ...
```

This pattern is common in the Python standard library; for example, [functools.lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) does this.

What type hints can I add to this decorator so that type checkers will be able to correctly infer the type of the decorated `my_func` either way it is decorated?

Comment: A decorator which doesn't change the signature, or prepends positional arguments, is easy to do. Other decorators (e.g. adding keyword arguments, or making some parameters have a default like your use of `functools.partial`) is not possible with the current typing system; [there's been talk of a mypy plugin](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1484), but that's specfically for `functools.partial`, not a decorator which internally calls `functools.partial`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `typing.overload`

```py
import functools
from typing import Callable, ParamSpec, TypeVar, overload, reveal_type


P = ParamSpec("P")
RT = TypeVar("RT")


@overload
def my_decorator(
    func: None = None, *, param: int = 42
) -> Callable[[Callable[P, RT]], Callable[P, RT]]:
    ...


@overload
def my_decorator(func: Callable[P, RT], *, param: int = 42) -> Callable[P, RT]:
    ...


def my_decorator(
    func: Callable[P, RT] | None = None, *, param=42
) -> functools.partial[Callable[[Callable[P, RT]], Callable[P, RT]]] | Callable[P, RT]:
    if func is None:
        return functools.partial(my_decorator, param=param)

    return func
```

Answer (score -1):

In this example, TypeVar('F', bound=Callable[..., Any]) is used to create a generic type variable F that represents a callable. The Optional[F] type hint for the func parameter allows the decorator to accept a function or None. The return type of the decorator is specified as F to ensure that the correct type is inferred based on how the decorator is applied.

This should help type checkers infer the correct type for my_func whether it's decorated without arguments or with the param argument.

Example:

```
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, Optional

F = TypeVar('F', bound=Callable[..., Any])

def my_decorator(func: Optional[F] = None, *, param: int = 42) -> F:
    if func is None:
        return functools.partial(my_decorator, param=param)
    ...
    return func
```